# logback. class not found exception

Tags: logback, appender, logback-classic

I am trying to add a DB appender into my logback configuration. 
Here is the part of the logback.xml file related to the issue:

```
<appender name="db" class="src.main.java.database.SqliteLogbackAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
        <driverClass>org.sqlite.JDBC</driverClass>
        <url>jdbc:sqlite:/home/db/logger.db</url>
    </connectionSource>
</appender>
```

The thing is, I use a custom appender, which is located in my *scr.main.java...etc* folder, but not in *logback-classic* library

When I run my application, I get the following error:

```
    09:02:06,682 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@31:78 - ActionException in Action for tag [appender] ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type src.main.java.database.SqliteLogbackAppender
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type src.main.java.database.SqliteLogbackAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:76)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:269)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:145)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:128)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:155)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:142)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:103)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
        at      at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
        at      at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:149)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:390)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:340)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:361)
        at      at interaction.Commander.<clinit>(Commander.java:14)
        at      at servlets.ExecuteServlet.<clinit>(ExecuteServlet.java:24)
        at      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:770)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
        at      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
        at      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1374)
        at      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type src.main.java.database.SqliteLogbackAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:69)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:45)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:34)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:52)
        at      ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.main.java.database.SqliteLogbackAppender
        at      at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1269)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:56)
        at      ... 46 common frames omitted
```

However, when I write classpath on *logback.xml* configuration, I am able to access file with IntellijIdea IDE interface (by clicking ctrl+left_mouse_button), so I believe there are no typos.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to use the fully qualified class name, including package, for your appender in the XML. Do not specify the path to the class.

"src.main.java.database.SqliteLogbackAppender" seems to include the Maven folders (src/main/java) and therefore likely isn't the actual class name.

Perhaps you meant just 'database.SqliteLogbackAppender'?

Comment: Thank your! That was exactly the issue!